# Pyplot legend/key, but for scale, like on maps

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm making a scatter plot, where the size of the markers is given by a list, so that each one is different. Is there some way to add a key that says 'this size circle is equivalent to this value' and so on? Like how maps have keys where it shows how say 1 inch is equal to 1 mile. 
If it's at all important, I'm doing this in jupyter notebook, but I don't think that should matter.

Edit: To clarify, each data point is an average of many others, and the size of each marker corresponds to how many data points went into calculating that average. So for example, one of the smaller dots is the median of 50 numbers, while one of the larger markers is for a data point that is the median of 150 numbers. So the numbers they correspond to aren't also a physical size, like a map would be.

I already have the markers scaled like I want them to be, what I'm wanting is a legend/key that indicates how the marker size relates to the value it comes from.

Comment: The question is not so clear. Should the marker's sizes represent some value, like *10pixel maker is 1inch, 12 pixel maker is 2 inch* or should the marker size actually be linked to the axes, such that a 1 inch marker has the length of 1 inch on the plot scale? The latter would be something that is encountered in topological maps, but reading your question I am not sure if that is what you mean. Can you tell what quantity should be on the axis and also if you want to plot on different scales (zoom the plot etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want your markers to be to scale. This is not possible with `plt.scatter()` as it's markersizes are always in pixels. An option is to use patches and add them to a PatchCollection.

Here is an example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection 

patches = []
coordinates = [(0,0), (2,0), (5,2), (1,7.6), (6,7), (2,4), (-1,5)]
sizes = 0.9+np.random.rand(len(coordinates),2)*1.99
print sizes

for i, co in enumerate(coordinates):
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle(co, sizes[i,0], sizes[i,1], ec="k")
    patches.append(rect)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5))
ax.set_aspect("equal")
colors = np.linspace(0, 1, len(patches))
collection = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.hsv, alpha=0.3)
collection.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(collection)

norm_scale = mpatches.Rectangle((7,-1), 2,2,  ec="k", facecolor="b")
ax.add_patch(norm_scale)
ax.set_xlim([-2,10])
ax.set_ylim([-2,10])
ax.set_ylabel("position [meters]")
ax.set_xlabel("position [meters]")
ax.set_title("Tents on a meddow")
ax.text(8,0.9, "2 m", color="w", ha="center", va="top")
ax.text(7.1,0, "2 m", color="w", ha="left", va="center", rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

giving the following plot, where the deep blue patch is kind of the key that shows a standard size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the argument `s` (size in points^2) in [plt.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter). Here is a MWE.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

value_and_markersize = {value:4**value for value in range(1, 10)}

x = [2, 4, 5, 7]
y = [0]*len(x)
s = [value_and_markersize[value] for value in x]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=s)
plt.show()
```

which produces,

[image]

Comment: This is not the requirement of the questioner. Instead, the question asks for a marker that is related to a value of the plot data. However, `markersize` is in points, so it cannot give a relation to the data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thx for your correction. I have just updated my answer.

Comment: Still not sure if that is what is asked for. The markersize is still in pixels, not data units. If you zoom your plot, scale changes, but markersize stays the same.